# I have a question about firebase and imageView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have such a problem with objects in which there is an Url image, and I need to take these objects from firebase realtimeDatabase and take Url from them and insert their method that creates the imageView and adds with the image to the linerleaut, everything works for me, I take everything all url objects I take but on the screen the imageView appears with the last added image, de still I can add a photo from the application,i tried Picasso and Bitmap but it doesn't work.

```
enter code here
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                linearLayoutShirt.removeAllViews();
                linearLayoutPant.removeAllViews();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Image object = postSnapshot.getValue(Image.class);
                 linearLayoutShirt.addView(test(dress, 300, 300));
                           
                    

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });




public LinearLayout test(final Image image, int weight, int height) {
        LinearLayout infoView = new LinearLayout(MyActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams infoViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        infoView.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);

        infoView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        infoView.setLayoutParams(infoViewParams);


        ImageView infoImageView = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(weight, height);
        infoImageView.setLayoutParams(params);

        new getImageFromUrl(infoImageView).execute(image.getImage());


        /*//Picasso.get().load(image.getImage()).into(infoImageView);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(dress.getImage()));
            infoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        infoView.addView(infoImageView);



        return infoView;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your question description with a clear and detailed explanation and also add your Log cat if you get any errors.

Comment: that's why I don’t get errors, everything works fine except for images, look at the photo only in the Pasadena add-on image, the picture is displayed

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what causes the problem a detailed explanation may work

Comment: I add photos from the application to firebase and at the same time I display these photos from firebase I take the url, but as you can see in the photo when I add a few photos, only the last added one is displayed, thanks for helping me and taking your time

Comment: First check if the images are correctly added to the firebase storage (*If you're using it*) If they are added properly head-over to the activity where you show the images then in your logcat you'll see the info tag in blue color thrown by picasso about the image loading issue. Examine that issue and do the changes according to it.

Comment: it seems to me it's all about the firebase storage rules, because when I put the url in the browser in the browser, I write this,                                                                              { error: { code: 403, message: "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation" } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your comment you're getting the following

```
{ error: { code: 403, message: "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation" } }
```

Then go to you're firebase database rules you'll find the following rules

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false //It is advised to set this rule as request.auth.uid != null to ensure no one will access to modify your data
  }
}
```

Now change the permission's according to your need like if you set `true` then anyone with the link can see the image from any platform and if you set `request.auth.uid != null` then only a registered user of your app can see the image.